Joining vectors with common elements from a list
I have a list of vectors and I want to join all the vectors inside the list which have some common components:
For example, I have:
list = [[1, 14], [3, 15], [4, 15], [5, 14], [8, 14], [9, 15], [10, 14], [11, 14]]

and I want to obtain:
[[1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14], [3, 4, 9, 15]].
I tried
a = np.unique(list)
grouped_vectors=[]
for k in a:
    grouped_vectors = np.argwhere(np.any(list[:]==k))
    print(grouped_vectors)

I don't know whether it makes any sense because I just get empty vectors

What programming language is this?  You're more likely to get helpful assistance if you tag the question with the programming language.

I think that I could guess the idea you wanted to implement.
You assume that the second item in each pair is an identifier of a group, so you want to group first items from all pairs where the second item is the same. Here is how I would do it.
import numpy as np
pairs = [[1, 14], [3, 15], [4, 15], [5, 14], [8, 14], [9, 15], [10, 14], [11, 14]]
coords = np.array(list(zip(*pairs))

for group_id in np.unique(coords[1]):
    grouped_vectors = coords[0][np.nonzero(coords[1] == group_id)
    grouped_vectors = np.append(grouped_vectors, [group_id])
    print(grouped_vectors)

This should print
[ 1  5  8 10 11 14]
[3 4 9 15]

